# Fit IFRAME content into page remove inner scrollbars

Tags: css

Hello I have an app where there is a top menu and a sidebar and an iframe all nested in a table. I know old school but that wasnt my decision.

I want the Iframe to fill the page based on the content length eliminate the iframe scrollbar and use the browser scrollbar to scroll.

Should I use javascript? can I just set everything to height 100% and then a specific overflow rule.

Right now I just have a min height on the iframe of 700px and a height of 100%

Answer (score 0):

Depending if you want to the iframe to postback or not, you might be better off using the jquery .load() method, with this you could do the following

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#mydivid').load('anypage.html')    
});
```

Doing this will eliminate the need to have an iframe altogether and might save you some hassle.

---

Alternatively if you wish to use the iframe you will need to calculate the height of the iframes content.

You can do this like so:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
       var iframeheight =  $('#myiframeid').find('body').height()    
       $('#myiframeid').height(iframeheight + 100)    
    });
```

You may need to run this after document ready as the iframe content may not complete loading when the $(document).ready() fires.